# Elasticsearch records from one type which DO NOT exists in other type

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have `1 index` with `2 types` in `Elasticsearch`. I want to query for all the records in `type1` that DO NOT exists in `type2`.

SQL equivalent would be something like;

```
SELECT * FROM index/type1 AS t1 WHERE t1.uid NOT IN (SELECT t2.uid FROM index/type2 AS t2)
```

Any suggestions on how I can go about this? I'm using elasticsearch-2.2.0 (Java API). Thank you!

Comment: How many documents (approx.) do you have in each type?

Comment: ~1 million in each type.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, would be sad if this would not be possible at all with Elasticsearch. Maybe the ["More like this" API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) could be of help here? However, I could not come up with a solution yet...

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is definitely not possible with Elasticsearch since it's not a [relational store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database).
There is a possibility to avoid passing terms explicitly but they should be present in some field of some document ([Terms lookup](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup)) :

```
{
  "bool": {
    "must_not": {
      "term": {
        "uid": {
          "index": "document-index",
          "type": "document-type",
          "id": "document-id",
          "path": "path-to-the-array-property-containing-the-terms"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```